# Smoothwall NOT giving out DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, local-area-network

I have a Smoothwall machine with 'green + red' setup.  The Smoothwall machine can see the outside world and I can connect to it from inside my network with its local address (I can also connect from the outside world with my static IP).

The problem is that machines on my network are not receiving DHCP.  They appear to try to get an IP, but fail.  Where would I start troubleshooting this?  The machines will receive DHCP from my wireless router, so I know my switch is good.  I have not tested the 'green' network card, but I assume its good.

Any advice would be helpful.  I am totally new to Smoothwall.

EDIT - DHCP is enabled.  Only one of my cards show up in the dropdown box on the DHCP config screen.

UNBELIEVABLE EMBARASSING EDIT - total newbie mistake...I had the network cables switched.  It is now giving out DHCP, but cannot connect to the outside world.  I think this is probably simply an issue with ip config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where would I start troubleshooting this?

run **TCPDump** on your client to take a look at the communication.

- Check to see if the Smoothwall has DHCP enabled
- Chekc to see where (Which NIC) DHCP is supposed to be offering IPs to

Comment: I see.. I would still use TCPDump to look at what kind of communication your DHCP server is having for requests coming from your client and offers by it.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I will run TCPDump when I have physical access later today.  It is in another building and for some reason I cant ssh to it...the web interface works though...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Everything seemed to be working but my internal machines could not access the external network (internet). The only thing that worked was to go to the update screen on the web interface and tell it to update. After that it magically started working (almost) fine.